# Bad axis calculation with arucos

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration, aruco

I'm looking at examples of OpenCV with wrinkles and how to identify the position.

It marks the lines well for me, but the orientation does not, the Z axis always goes to the upper left corner.[image: axis calculation]

This is my code:

```
float markerLength = 0.2;

    // Set coordinate system
    cv::Mat objPoints(4, 1, CV_32FC3);
    objPoints.ptr<cv::Vec3f>(0)[0] = cv::Vec3f(-markerLength/2.f,  markerLength/2.f, 0);
    objPoints.ptr<cv::Vec3f>(0)[1] = cv::Vec3f( markerLength/2.f,  markerLength/2.f, 0);
    objPoints.ptr<cv::Vec3f>(0)[2] = cv::Vec3f( markerLength/2.f, -markerLength/2.f, 0);
    objPoints.ptr<cv::Vec3f>(0)[3] = cv::Vec3f(-markerLength/2.f, -markerLength/2.f, 0);

    cv::Mat cameraMatrix(3,3,cv::DataType<double>::type);
    cv::setIdentity(cameraMatrix);
    cv::Mat distCoeffs(4,1,cv::DataType<double>::type);
    distCoeffs.at<double>(0) = 0;
    distCoeffs.at<double>(1) = 0;
    distCoeffs.at<double>(2) = 0;
    distCoeffs.at<double>(3) = 0;

    std::vector<cv::Vec3d> rvecs, tvecs;

    while (m_videoCap.isOpened()) {
        m_videoCap >> m_frame;

        if (!m_frame.empty()) {
            // Draw marker centers
            cv::Mat outputImage = m_frame.clone();

            std::vector<int> markerIds;
            std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>> markerCorners, rejectedCandidates;
            cv::Ptr<cv::aruco::DetectorParameters> parameters = cv::aruco::DetectorParameters::create();
            cv::Ptr<cv::aruco::Dictionary> dictionary = cv::aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(cv::aruco::DICT_4X4_250);
            cv::aruco::detectMarkers(m_frame, dictionary, markerCorners, markerIds, parameters, rejectedCandidates);
            cv::aruco::drawDetectedMarkers(outputImage, markerCorners);

            int nMarkers = markerCorners.size();
            std::vector<cv::Vec3d> rvecs(nMarkers), tvecs(nMarkers);

            for (int i = 0; i < nMarkers; i++) {
                auto& corners = markerCorners[i];

                cv::solvePnP(objPoints, corners, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs.at(i), tvecs.at(i));
                cv::drawFrameAxes(outputImage, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs[i], tvecs[i], 0.1, 2);
            }

            m_Pixmap = cvMatToQPixmap(outputImage);
            emit newPixmapCaptured();
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

---

EDIT:
I've changed the camera initialization to this one as suggested Christoph Rackwitz:

```
    // f[px] = x[px] * z[m] / x[m]
    float focalLen = 950 * 1.3f / 0.45f;
    cv::Matx33f cameraMatrix(focalLen, 0.0f,     (1280-1) / 2.0f,
                             0.0f,     focalLen, (780-1) / 2.0f,
                             0.0f,     0.0f,     1.0f);
```

And now it works fine:

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Proper [mcve], please, which works with a single example image rather than needing a camera or a video, and including the said example input image.

Comment: Probably your camera has neither identity cameraMatrix nor 0 distortions. Tey starting with setting the (0,2) and (1,2) entries of the camera matrix fo imhe center (last column = (w/2, h/2, 1). And (0,0) and (1,1) to some bigger values. If that is not enough, calibrate your camera and use the real cam matrix and distortions.

Comment: `cameraMatrix` is just an identity in your code. insufficient. requires focal length and optical center at least. distortion coefficients don't account for this, the broken K does. measure some object in view. calculate x[m] / z[m] * f[px] = x[px], solve for f[px]. other variables are physical distance and width, and apparent (pixel) width. -- beyond that I'd recommend a thorough introduction to the whole thing. and do this in python. C++ is terrible for prototyping. -- aruco has its own pose estimation. do not use `solvePnP`

Comment: looks like `solvePnP` is indeed recommended, and they deprecated the aruco module's wrapper on top of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cv::Mat cameraMatrix(3,3,cv::DataType<double>::type);
cv::setIdentity(cameraMatrix);
```

This is insufficient. The camera matrix must contain a sensible focal length as well as optical center.

A proper camera matrix looks like

```
[[  f,  0, cx],
 [  0,  f, cy],
 [  0,  0,  1]]
```

You can get that entire matrix (and distortion coefficients) from calibration, but that's hard.

You can also just calculate those values. That'll be close enough.

- Optical center: `cx = (width-1) / 2` and similarly for `cy`.
- Focal length

  1. Take a picture of some easily measured object, like... an aruco marker, or a yard stick
  2. Measure its physical distance `z[m]` to the camera and the physical length `x[m]` of it
  3. Measure its length in pixels `x[px]`
  4. Calculate `f[px] = x[px] * z[m] / x[m]`

You can forget about distortion coefficients for now. Set them all to 0. Those will be relevant if your camera has noticeable pincushion or barrel distortion from its lens.

---

You can use [`Mat::zeros`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a56daa006391a670e9cb0cd08e3168c99) and [`Mat::eye`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a458874f0ab8946136254da37ba06b78b) to initialize your matrices.

You can generate a Mat from literal element values with predefined fixed-size matrix types like [`Matx33f`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/d84/group__core__basic.html#ga118a383f60581636c7c8ab180cbb155e)

```
Matx33f K(1, 2, 3,
          4, 5, 6,
          7, 8, 9);
```

Or using [`Mat_`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/df/dfc/classcv_1_1Mat__.html):

```
Mat K = (Mat_<float>(3,3) <<
    1, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6,
    7, 8, 9);
```

---

It looks like [`estimatePoseSingleMarkers`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d6a/group__aruco.html#gaba7f1e107f93451e2bc43b8ea96eef8c) got deprecated. That must have happened with the v4.7 release or maybe the v4.6 release already.

Docs recommend using `solvePnP`.

The advantage of that is: you get to decide the marker's coordinate system, i.e. where the origin lies (center or corner) and which way the axes point.

Downside: it's a little inconvenient to be expected to generate the object points.

---

OpenCV's aruco module is still kind of a mess. There's an enum called [`PatternPositionType`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d6a/group__aruco.html#ga27275294ed214f3872ddef00d86d40d5) (used in `EstimateParameters`). They use the terms "clockwise" and "counter-clockwise", while *assuming* that's relative to a coordinate system with Z going into the surface of the marker. Better terms would have been "positive" and "negative" rotation around the Z axis.